# Relationship between pointer and inheritance c++ oop

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, inheritance, relationship

Can any one please express a short code of c++ which should show the relationship between pointer and inheritance.

I believe the below code refers to my problem

```
class Animal { 
  public:   
    virtual void MakeSound(const char* pNoise) { ... }   
    virtual void MakeSound() { ... } 
};

class Dog : public Animal { 
  public:   
    virtual void MakeSound() {... }
};

int main() {   
  Animal* a = new Dog();   
  Dog* d = new Dog();  
  a->MakeSound("bark");   
  d->MakeSound("bark"); // Does not compile  
  return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You hide base class `MakeSound` with override of other `MakeSound` so it does not participate in overload resolution. Either override both or neither in `Dog` or rename one of those as `MakeNoise`.

Comment: Can someone please share a proper solution with complete code?

Comment: Solution of what problem? You posted ill-formed program and I listed 3 ways to fix it.

Comment: can you tell me if is it good?

    virtual void MakeSound() 
};

int main() {   
  Animal* a = new Dog();   
  Dog* d = new Dog();  
  a->MakeSound("bark");   
  d->MakeNoise("bark"); // Does not compile  
  return 0; 
}

Comment: if you really want, you can call `d->Animal::MakeSound("bark")`, but I don't think it's recommended practice

Answer (score 0):

The two really have very little to do with each other, the one point of intersection is that in order to take advantage of polymorphic behavior (virtual members) you have to use either pointers or references. If you assign a derived instance to an actual base instance (as opposed to assigning the address of the derived to a base pointer or initializing a base reference with a derived instance) then any derived functionality will simply be lost (the usual term calls that object slicing).

And note in your example there isn't much point to a virtual void make_sound(char const *), much more common would be to use the virtual void make_sound() form and the derived type knows what kind of sound to produce.

Comment: Can you suggest a detailed code which should sufficient my request?